# Estimated bounds for margin of error in US election results?

Tags: united-states, election, statistics

When one sets out to measure a thing, one expects various sorts of errors to occur in the measurement.... depending on context one might have: errors with the measuring instrument, errors due to limitations of the instrument user, standard sampling errors, etc. etc.

Weirdly, I can't seem to find estimates of errors for US elections at any level.  County, State, National.  For an election the size of the US presidential election (>150M sample points) there's almost surely >1 data recording error.  However, there's almost surely <150M data recording errors.  Does anyone attempt to estimate the margin of error in election results?  If not, why not?  If so, are these compiled somewhere for easy viewing?

Comment: This strikes me as one of these things that cannot be estimated with a high enough degree of confidence to be useful.

Comment: Most states establish a threshold for a recount of either a 1 percentage point of votes cast difference, or a 0.5 percentage point of votes cast difference. This is the operational definition of margin of vote counting error that is used to trigger efforts to remedy any error. As the answer provided indicates, however, even 0.5 percentage points is an order of magnitude greater than the high end of the uncertainty in the counting process that is revealed empirically.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Nominally, there *is* no error, because every single vote is counted exactly once.  There's no extrapolation involved (like with polls) or imprecision in the measurement (like with experimental results), so there's no need for a margin of error.

That said, in the real world, screwups *can* occur.  People [misplace the votes](https://www.nytimes.com/2020/11/11/us/puerto-rico-ballots.html), or [fail to upload them](https://apnews.com/article/2nd-georgia-county-find-uncounted-votes-018eac6ac24733d63d356ee76f485530), or even just have data entry errors.  But none of these are conducive to measuring a margin of error.  For example: Accidentally recording 32,456 votes instead of 23,456 votes is just as likely as accidentally recording 23,465 - but one of them is off by 9,000 votes, and the other is only off by 9.

Really, the only way to get a good handle on how "wrong" the final vote totals are is to do a recount and see how far off they were (although then you have the question of whether the recount also screwed up...).
Ballotpedia [has a page](https://ballotpedia.org/Noteworthy_recounts_in_the_United_States) tracking notable recounts and linking to a [FairVote report](https://www.fairvote.org/recounts) on recounts 2000-2015.  The results:

> The average shift across all recounts was 282 votes, which accounted for 0.019 percent of the statewide vote in those races. In the seven recounts in which the total votes cast were above two million, the margin shift averaged 0.016 percent of the vote. In the eight cases in which the total votes cast were fewer than one million, the margin shift averaged 0.039 percent.

So, to put a real-world context on this, lets look at California in 2016, which cast the most votes of any state.  There were 14,181,595 votes cast there - applying half of the 0.019% shift (because one miscounted vote causes a shift of 2 votes), that's a difference of +/- 1347 votes.  One *could* use that as a margin of error, but it's so small in comparison as to be meaningless in almost any context.

For comparison, that margin of error on measuring the distance from NYC to DC (roughly 200 miles) is 120 feet.

Comment: Your vote shift is only true if all miscounted ballots were a valid vote for another. But your point holds the difference is somwhere between 1400 and 2800 out of 14,000,000.

Comment: @AzorAhai-him- That's a good point.  And I also didn't account for third party votes either, now that I think about it.

Comment: I think that's OK? The summary is that you could say about 1 in 10,000 ballots in an average election is in the wrong column, if "NA" was a column.

Comment: Another way to look at it is that this is describing the worst case: all the errors shifting from the winner to the loser.